# ошибка компилятора pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

при запуске exe'шника вылетает ошибка

```
Fatal Error detected
failed to execute script 'scriptname'
```

В чем проблема? Понимаю условия размыты , нужен опыт уже сталкивающихся с подобными проблемами

- Код в py запускается как надо
- вложенные в код файлы находятся в одной папке с exe'шником
- компилировал через Auto py to exe(как я понял это просто интерфейс для pyinstaller)
- единственный пойманный ворн : `'Warnings written to C:\Users\XSPACE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp130wd11s\build\hokku\warn-hokku.txt'`
- если не знаете решения проблемы предложите другой компилятор 
  заранее спасибо!

Comment: Обычно у меня такая ошибка была когда не находилось нужного файла т.е. вы добавили какой то файл но при сборке он не добавился я вообще брал и после каждой функции в коде выводил сообщение что мол отработала такая то функция и при сборке флаг надо поставить для дебага

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/473134 может здесь что найдёте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таки разобрался сам. Лучше использовать cx_Freeze. Именно мне помогло полное удаление библиотек и переустановка питона на более старую версию. Похоже , что компилятор и питон просто не "сдружились".